# No Such Module 'Alamofire','SwiftyJson','UiKiT'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am getting this build error on an existing project when I try to build project.

> no such module 'Alamofire'

When I remove that line, then it start point to swiftyJson as

> no such module 'SwiftyJson'

and when i remove that line and build again it start pointing UiKit as

> no such module UiKit

Yesterday, I updated my xcode to 10.3 as I got a new update so installed that and after that I am getting this issue.
Then I downloaded previous version xcode 10.2.1 from apple developer site and now again I am getting this issue.
When I make a new project there is no issue like this.

i have tried reinstalling pods after some sort of search but not getting rid of this error.

Comment: run `pod deintegrate && pod install`, and possibly `pod update` to make sure libraries are fine. Also go to Issue Navigator and see if there are any other errors there

Answer (score 0):

delete derived data: go to `Xcode` -> `preferences` -> `Locations` -> then delete derived data

if that doesn't work try restarting your mac

Comment: I have deleted drive data and restarted mac but still getting same error. @DisplayName

Comment: go to product->clean build folder, delete derived data, close xcode and reopen, then product -> build

Comment: Done this also not working same issue not found Alamofire, SwiftyJson . @kjoe

Comment: unplug then plug back in

Comment: or try cleaning it with bleach

Answer (score 0):

Clean the project with 'command + shift + K'

or

if your project is uploaded in git repository, just remove whole project to trash and clone it